# WebRTC Data Channel server to clients UDP communication

Tags: javascript, node.js, udp, webrtc

Is it possible to use WebRTC Data Channels on Node.js in a way that mimics the functionality (and preferably API) of Socket.io (WebSockets) except using UDP?

In essence I want to have a server running Node.js with which browser clients can establish a full duplex bi directional UDP connection via JavaScript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a WebRTC module for node.js: https://js-platform.github.io/node-webrtc/

The installation can be really cumbersome (to say the least) but if you succeed you'll be able to make your node.js server act as a WebRTC peer just as browsers do. This way you'd be able to open a Data Channel between a browser and your node.js server.

We have this in use in our research project to evaluate performance characteristics.

Comment: Is there an interface to connect the node.js server to multiple browser clients and handle them similar to how multiple websocket clients are handled in Socket.io?

Comment: Perhaps you could use one of the WebRTC JS wrappers. The problem with wrappers such as webrtc.io or orca.js is that they are built to be used on browsers so you would most probably have to adapt them to be used on the server side.

Comment: So those wrappers allow a browser client to act as an end-point in communication with multiple other browsers?

Comment: @Willem, if you used a browser client to act as an end-point, you then could not forward the information over UDP.

Comment: @bwtrent maybe end-point is not the correct term. I mean as a kind of central hub for all communication. So one peer can communicate with all other peers, but the other peers can only communicate with this one peer.

If that's possible with these wrappers then I guess they can be rewritten for the purpose I need them in Node.js?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in theory you should be able to to do this. However, you'll need a node module that supports WebRTC data channels, so that you can connect to it like any other peer. Unfortunately, scanning through the [current modules](https://nodejsmodules.org/new/tags/webrtc), I don't see one that implements the data channel.

The other thing to note is the WebRTC data channels can be configured for different [reliability modes](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html#rtcdatachannel) with the reliable mode being implemented with SCTP ([Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=886134) and [Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=1493)).

When testing the data channels I would recommend using Firefox since the WebRTC work was split such that Chrome initially focused on PeerConnection and Firefox on DataChannel (so Firefox is still ahead in their implementation of the DataChannel).

Comment: Thanks, that confirms my suspicions.
I hope someone creates a module which mimicks the API of Websockets with support for multiple connected clients.

Comment: I'm actually most interested in the unreliable mode (0 retransmits). Does WebRTC support this via SCTP or something else?

Comment: I think the unreliable mode was initially built on [RTP in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=1494), but that everything will [eventually be based on SCTP](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=1430).

The SCTP library that Mozilla uses with the data channel is here: https://code.google.com/p/sctp-refimpl/

Comment: @tomvLine so if I does not specify reliability mode, WebRTC DataChannel will uses UDP as its transport ?

Comment: The SCTP userspace implementation tunnels over UDP, but theoretically the OS could support it natively. Take a look at the implementation that Firefox uses for details: https://code.google.com/p/sctp-refimpl/